# Replace div background url by image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace div background url by image src?

```
<img class='active' src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/12/547/w128h1281387216564facebook3.png"/>
<div class='content-box'></div>
<div class='btn'>CLICK</div>

.content-box{
background-image: url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/12/547/w128h1281387216591googleWhite.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
}
.btn{
position: fixed;
left: 200px;
top: 73px; 
width: 40px;
height:40px;
}
```

Tried it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
        var imgSrc = $('.active').attr('src');
        $('.content-box').css('background-image', 'url(imgSrc)'); 
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fresa150/H2aWF/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`imgSrc` is a variable hence you should not use it in quotes.

Use

```
$('.content-box').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2aWF/1/)

Comment: @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy )))

Comment: @Satpal very quciker indeed just few seconds before you posted and then i

Answer (score 1):

You need to do :

```
$('.content-box').css('background-image', "url("+imgSrc+")");
```

As `imgSrc` is a variable it will not be recognized in double quotes so you need to concatenate variable

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/9T88T/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
$('.content-box').css('background-image', "url('"+imgSrc+"')");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/H2aWF/2/)